# Add folder to winrar using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using below script to copy some folders from source to destination.

https://techblog.dorogin.com/powershell-how-to-recursively-copy-a-folder-structure-excluding-some-child-folders-and-files-a1de7e70f1b#.uw7nnhmd2

```
$from = '\\DB01\Test'
$to = New-Item -Path '\\DB01\SQLBackups\DBTest\' -ItemType Directory -Name ("Backup_$(Get-Date -f yyyy_MM_dd)")

$exclude = @("*.log", "*.csv")
$excludeMatch = @("logs")

Get-ChildItem -Path $from -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | 
          where { $excludeMatch -eq $null -or $_.FullName.Replace($from, "") -notmatch $excludeMatch } |
          Copy-Item -Destination {
            if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
              Join-Path $to $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($from.length)
            } else {
              Join-Path $to $_.FullName.Substring($from.length)
            }
           } -Force -Exclude $exclude
```

Now, I want to add the folder created in $to variable to a zip file in same location with Backup_$(Get-Date -f yyyy_MM_dd).zip as filename. How do I achieve this using powershell 2.0?

I tried below but it didn't work.

```
"%ProgamFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -r "Backup_$(Get-Date -f yyyy_MM_dd)" "$to"
```

Comment: well, assuming the command is correct ``."path_to_executable" a -ep1 -r "Backup_$(Get-Date -f yyyy_MM_dd)" "$to"``

Comment: Yes, the executable path is correct. But still it didn't work.

Comment: `"%ProgamFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe"` should be `"$($env:ProgramFiles)\winrar\rar.exe"` %% is for batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the full path to the archive being created, if not it will be created in the path that powershell is run with (Likely *C:\Users\USERNAME*).

If you split the destination from the `$to` variable you can use that later during the archive command:

```
$from = '\\DB01\Test'
$backup_location = '\\DB01\SQLBackups\DBTest'
$backup_folder = "Backup_$(Get-Date -f yyyy_MM_dd)"
$to = New-Item "$backup_location\$backup_folder" -ItemType Directory

$exclude = @("*.log", "*.csv")
$excludeMatch = @("logs")

Get-ChildItem -Path $from -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | 
          where { $excludeMatch -eq $null -or $_.FullName.Replace($from, "") -notmatch $excludeMatch } |
          Copy-Item -Destination {
            if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
              Join-Path $to $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($from.length)
            } else {
              Join-Path $to $_.FullName.Substring($from.length)
            }
           } -Force -Exclude $exclude 


Start-Process -FilePath "$($env:ProgramFiles)\winrar\rar.exe" -ArgumentList "a -ep1 -r `"$backup_location\$backup_folder.rar`" `"$to`""
```

Answer (score 1):

try Something like this (dont forget the dot)

```
. "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\winrar.exe" a -ep "C:\temp\currentrar.rar" "C:\temp\filetoadd.txt"
```